# Matrix differential equation and closed orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

everyone.

I am asking for a reference for the nonexistence of closed orbits (periodic orbits) of Matrix differential equations of the form
\begin{equation}
v\prime = M(v)\cdot v
\end{equation}
where $M(v)$ is a (nonconstant) matrix depending smoothly on $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am really not an expert in Differential Equations. Advanced thanks for any help/suggestion/reference.

Comment: Were you thinking about Floquet Theory?

Comment: Floquet Theory, in its standard form, probably.won't work here since $M$ depends on $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways I can think of:

- Proving the existence of a globally asymptotically stable equilibrium, for example with a [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function), rules out periodic orbits.
- Showing the system is monotone, most easily done with the Kamke condition (which consists of checking for a sign pattern in the Jacobian), rules out the existence of *attracting* periodic orbits, see Theorem 1.17 in [here](http://cts.nthu.edu.tw/Mathematics/english/lecnotes/2006/MonotoneDynamics.pdf).
- Proving that the maximal [Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) is less than zero also rules out periodic orbits-- however, this can be quite hard to do (usually Lyapunov exponents are only estimated numerically).

If you add to the question the specific $M(v)$ you have in mind, we might be able to provide more help.

EDIT: A couple more I forgot about:

- [Dulac's criterion](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/uk/dynsys/ds2/limit/Dulac/Dulac.html).
- Index theory, see Section 2 of [this](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/224/cds140b-perorb.pdf).

Comment: @AlonsoOchoa, see edit for a couple of simpler tests.